# Can't reference ValueConverter class in XAML even with xmlns correctly typed

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community with Update 1 with the 'Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools' install component, on Windows 10 Pro. I have created a project using the Blank Windows Phone template targeting Windows Phone 8.1. I'm following the [MVVM tutorial on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg521153%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), and I've hit a problem using an [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter) class for a view. Here's what I've done so far:

Created my IValueConverter class:

```
namespace Realgia.WindowsPhone
{
    public class ValueConverterDate : IValueConverter
    {
        // This converts the DateTime object to the string to display.
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, string language)
        {
            // Retrieve the format string and use it to format the value.
            string formatString = parameter as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formatString))
            {
                return string.Format(
                    new CultureInfo(language), formatString, value);
            }
            // If the format string is null or empty, simply call ToString()
            // on the value.
            return value.ToString();
        }

        // No need to implement converting back on a one-way binding 
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the class has been created in my main project, in namespace `Realgia.WindowsPhone`. Also note that the interface I'm using is `Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter`, not `System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter` which is used in the tutorial (I believe the tutorial is out of date?)

In the XAML of my UserControl, I've added an xmlns for my namespace containing the ValueConverter:

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Realgia.WindowsPhone"
```

Now I'm attempting to add the converter as a resource to my UserControl in the same XAML file. As you can see below intellisense actually picks up my ValueConverterDate class:

[image]

So the complete XAML code is:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Realgia.WindowsPhone.View.MeasurementsView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Realgia.WindowsPhone"

    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:ValueConverterDate x:Key="ValueConverterDate" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I keep getting the following error on compile:

> Unknown type 'ValueConverterDate' in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:Realgia.WindowsPhone;assembly=Realgia.WindowsPhone,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

I'm really struggling to understand why the XAML parser can't find this class, because it's picked up by intellisense, the namespace of this calss is definately Realgia.WindowsPhone (as you can see from the class definition) and my xmlns points to this namespace.

I've tried the following:

- Cleaning and rebuilding
- Referencing another class (just a plain old empty class) - same problem
- Moving the class to be nested inside the codebehind of the XAML file instead of in it's own code file
- Reset my PC and reinstalled Visual Studio
- Read and re-read the XAML documentation
- Removed the `<converters:ValueConverterDate x:Key="ValueConverterDate" />` bit of code, compile (it compiles successfully), then re-add the code and attempt to compile again
- <s>tried using `xmlns:converters="using:Realgia.WindowsPhone"` instead of `xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Realgia.WindowsPhone"`</s> See edit:

> EDIT  See comments, the solution in fact turned out to be to use
>   `xmlns:converters="using:Realgia.WindowsPhone"` instead of
>   `xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Realgia.WindowsPhone"`
>   I'm sure I tried this once and it didn't work, not sure if I made a mistake the first time or whether something else I did 'fixed' this (e.g. closing the solution, rebooting my computer)

I'm beginning to suspect the issue may be because I'm using `Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter`, instead of `System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter`, but `System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter` is in assembly PresentationFramework.dll, and I can't find this assembly anywhere using search in Visual Studio 'Add Reference'. If anyone can explain the history of this (why are there two IValueConverter interfaces in two different assemblies?) maybe that would help - it's not mentioned in the docs. There is only a slight difference between the two (one takes a string argument, the other takes a CultureInfo argument).

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the view and value converter in the same project?  Perhaps you're missing a project reference to your main project from the view project?

Comment: I have a WP 8.1 project and I'm using the `xmlns:converters="using:Realgia.WindowsPhone"` syntax successfully. What's the error when you use the `using` syntax?

Comment: I just gave this a spin, a WP8.1 app (non-silverlight) requires the 'using' xmlns syntax and uses Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter. If you created a WP8.1 silverlight app, you should use the clr-namespace: xmlns syntax and implement System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter. Given that you only have the first valueconverter, I'd say you need to stick to the using syntax. Also double-check you're not running into an intellisense glitch, I've see these kinds of errors with WPF projects before, but they are only generated by intellisense, the actual compile works fine (check the 'output' pane).

Comment: The view and value converter are in the same project. It's a non-silverlight WP8.1 app. I just tried again to use the `using` syntax and it works! I'm sure I did try this before and it didn't compile, not sure if I made a mistake or what, I seem to remember it giving me the same error about not finding the class in the namespace. If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just gave this a spin, a WP8.1 app (non-silverlight) requires the '`using`' xmlns syntax and uses `Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter`. If you created a WP8.1 silverlight app, you should use the clr-namespace: xmlns syntax and implement `System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter`. Given that you only have the first valueconverter, I'd say you need to stick to the `using` syntax. Also double-check you're not running into an intellisense glitch, I've see these kinds of errors with WPF projects before, but they are only generated by intellisense, the actual compile works fine (check the 'output' pane).

Comment: Thanks Evert, `xmlns:converters="using:Realgia.WindowsPhone"` did the trick! I'm struggling to find any documentation on `using` in an xmlns, do you know what the difference between `using` and `clr-namespace`?

Comment: I can't find any reference documentation describing the rationale for the change from clr-namespace to using, but at least the using part is documented on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185594.aspx (which seems a bit hard to find through google).